# Different behaviour of loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops

I have little problem.

My input:
 **configurations** - collection that contains for at this moment 2 different objects.

Result looks like was executed two times but with the same **parameters**. If put break point inside the loop, I see different objects. What I am doing wrong?

```
    List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

    foreach (var configuration in configurations)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => new DieToolRepo().UpdateDieTool(configuration));
        thread.Start();
        threads.Add(thread);
    }

    threads.WaitAll();
```

Expected result: 
[image]

What I have:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "result looks like was executed two times but with the same parameters"?
Please show us the whole code and your expected/actual output. Also, paste the code instead of putting an image

Comment: As @NahuelIanni asked, please show code for `DieToolRepo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's disambiguition with the variable 'configuration'.

Following @HenkHolterman's advice, I'm first posting a cleaner, more precise, solution:

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
foreach (var configuration in configurations)
{
    var threadConfiguration = configuration;
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => DieToolRepo().UpdateDieTool(threadConfiguration );
    thread.Start();
    threads.Add(thread);
}
threads.WaitAll();
```

Additionally, you can also work it out with for loop:

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
for (var index=0; index< configurations.Length; index++)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => DieToolRepo().UpdateDieTool(configurations[index]));
    thread.Start();
    threads.Add(thread);
}
threads.WaitAll();
```

This happens because of the variable 'configuration' is the same for all threads, when this runs.
Using this method will create a new copy of Index (localIndex - copied by value), so the shared use of configurations will give different configuration every call.

Though, I'm sure there's a better way to handle those threads, and use safer values accordingly.

Comment: I do not know why you get "-" because with "for" loop everything work perfect

Comment: Thank you :) In that case, can you please marked as solved? (I encountered this exact problem, so I knew this would solve it)

Comment: Thank you so much:)

Comment: It's not about for/foreach, you can get the same fix with foreach and `var localCopy = configuration;`

Comment: @HenkHolterman, thought about it, but I had a hunch configuration is a class, and would pass by reference, which might still not work due same disambiguition.

Comment: No, the foreach will produce different references each time. Also, I think this is fixed in later versions of C#, the OP must be using VS2010 or so.

Comment: Happened to me on VS Community 2013 at the least.
@MrocznyArturek, it's worth trying back the 'foreach', I'll update the code accordingly - can you let us know if it helped?

Comment: In "For" case localIndex is not required. Just: "... new DieToolRepo().UpdateDieTool(configurations[index])"

Comment: Thanks, updated answer accordingly for future reference

Comment: I didn't get how configuration variable is same for all threads? What do you mean? Isnt configuration different every iteration in foreach?

Comment: I would guess that the way the references are passed to all threads, are update retroactively.
According to @HenkHolterman, this should have been fixed since VS2010, but I'm pretty sure I've reproduced it in at aleast VS Community 2013. Took me some time to realize this and overcome this issue, first time I encountered it.

Comment: The thing is called "capturing the loop variable" or "closing over". You can google it, plenty of questions on SO as well.